# Updating GPlus Signature Error

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-plus, signature-error

I've installed Resurrection Remix 2.0 ROM (i'm a big fan of), and when I want to update Google Plus to the newest version I receive a signature error for installed version, when I go to application manager I can't find it there to uninstall it.

It works fine but I want to update it.

Can anyone help me with this.

I'm using SG2
Kernel thoravukk 2.57
Rom: Resurrection Remix 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by using Titanium backup, because G+ was set as system app. I couldn't update it so I changed the condition for G+ from system app. to user app using titanium backup by long press on the app and select change to user app from the menu.

Thank you all for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what launcher your ROM has, but some launchers (like ADW) have the option to long-press an application icon for a dialog to appear. In this dialog you have an option to go to `App Details`. In that screen there should be an uninstall button.