# Package error "package file was not signed correctly"  when updating Google+

Tags: google-play-store, updates, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating GPlus Signature Error](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23620/updating-gplus-signature-error)

In trying to update Google+ I receive: "package file was not signed correctly uninstall the previous copy of the app and try again".

The problem is I can't find Google+ app in the app manager.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Galaxy SII I9100
Android 4.04
Rom: Resurrection Remix 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try deleting the app folder entirely in a file browser of your choice. You should be able to find a folder called:

```
/Apps/Google+
```

If you remove this folder completely, there should be no confusion as to whether the app is installed on your phone or not. From [this](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/th3ory-rom-bionic/182861-help-needed-please-package-file-not-signed-correctly.html) forum thread I would also like to point out that it might be an issue with Titanium Backup if you use that. Try removing any backed up versions of the app in that app as well for good measure.

Comment: I managed to do that from titanium backup by converting google plus from system app into user app and uninstall it normally, Thank you for your advice...

Comment: There is no folder called /Apps/Google+. The system apps are located in /system/app/ and inside here are files, not folders.